# React - Make search and filter work on a given data at same time irrespective of the order of change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, codesandbox

I am retrieving a list of data and search for a title name from a list of [todos](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/), then i have built with [Switch Material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/switches/) a component to toggle the todos that are completed and not.

You can see the full demo here => https://codesandbox.io/s/so-68247206-forked-sx9kv?file=/src/App.js

Now i want to search the todos title in the list of the todos/tasks that are completed or not completed, depending on where you switch, at the moment the search goes through in all the todos.

To reproduce the case

- Launch the app in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-68247206-forked-sx9kv?file=/src/App.js)
- Switch the toggle
- Search for elements (It search in all the todos list and not through the completed or not completed result list )

The relevant code is the following

The search method

```
  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    let value = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    let result = [];
    result = tasks.filter((data) => {
      return data.title.search(value) !== -1;
    });
    setFilteredData(result);
  };
```

The complete method

```
  const getCompleted = (e, value) => {
    let result = [];
    let switchValue = e.target.checked;
    result = tasks.filter(({ completed }) => completed === switchValue);
    setFilteredData(result);
    setIsCompleted(!switchValue);
    setText(isCompleted ? "Yes" : "No");
  };
```

How can i change my search method to look through the todos completed and not completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save both the search value and switch value in state and use a useEffect to filter the values. Check the below fork of your code

https://codesandbox.io/s/so-68247206-forked-nkuf3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This is the best solution, although the initial list is filtering already the not completed, haw can i solve that?

Comment: It's because we were setting the isCompleted default in useState. Also modified the filtering to check for boolean value in isCompleted , check here https://codesandbox.io/s/so-68247206-forked-xn3nn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thanks, i have learnt a lot with your answer

Answer (score 1):

There's a slight modification to your `handleSearch` method. When you're filtering your `tasks`, you can check if you have toggled on the completed switch using the `isCompleted` state. All you need is an additional condition inside your `filter` method that takes care of the is completed scenario. The following updated `handleSearch` method works fine.

```
  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    let value = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    let result = [];
    console.log(value);
    let filterCompleted = false;
    if (!isCompleted) filterCompleted = true;
    console.log({ filterCompleted });
    result = tasks.filter((data) => {
      if (filterCompleted)
        return data.completed && data.title.search(value) !== -1;
      else return !data.completed && data.title.search(value) !== -1;
    });
    setFilteredData(result);
  };
```

I use a local variable inside `handleSearch` to check if you have toggled on the completed button. If it's toggled on, while filtering I only filter those tasks that have the `completed` property set to `true` and vice versa. You can check that this works here https://codesandbox.io/s/so-68247206-forked-4iz7p?file=/src/App.js.

**Note**: I feel the `isCompleted` state is working on a reverse logic. When I toggle on the switch, the `isCompleted` is `false` but it should be `true` instead. You can try fixing this or renaming the state (if the reverse logic was intentional and you only messed up with naming the state). Anyhow this doesn't affect the solution but makes it difficult to debug and adds some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter in `handleSearch` searches from the original tasks array which might not be what you want :

```
   const handleSearch = (event) => {
    let value = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    let result = tasks; //Assigning initial value to result
    if(isCompleted){
     result =  result.filter(({ completed }) => completed === isCompleted)
    } //only if isCompleted is true, filter the array first
    result = result.filter((data) => {
      return data.title.search(value) !== -1;
    }); //Filter the array based on search term
    setFilteredData(result);
  };
```

Also, your `getCompleted` is setting the inverse value of the checkbox with `(!switchValue)`. You can change that along with the extra param `value` which is not accounted for in your `onChange` call.

```
 const getCompleted = (e) => {
    
    let switchValue = e.target.checked;
    let result = tasks.filter(({ completed }) => completed === switchValue);
    setFilteredData(result);
    setIsCompleted(switchValue);
    setText(switchValue ? "Yes" : "No"); //Is text state variable really required?
  };
```

Here I have tried to fix it : [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-68247206-forked-mgnwf?file=/src/App.js)

That being said, I would recommend not having multiple state variables which can be derived from each other. Your `text` state variable is only used for view purposes and its value completely relies on `isCompleted`. You could have used a conditional operator in your return function to show "Yes/No" instead of a new state variable.